# Let $K$ be a compact set in $\Bbb C$, and $f: K\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$ be an analytic function. Is $f$ a uniformly differentiable function on $K$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is a natural question in complex analysis. Let $K$ be a compact set in $\Bbb C$, and $f: K\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$ be an analytic function.  Is $f$ uniformly differentiable?

{{Here $f$ is called analytic, if we can extened $f$ to an open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb C$, that contains $K$, such that $f:U \rightarrow \Bbb C$ is analytic (differentiable on $U$). }}

{{Moreover, if $f$ is analytic on $K$, then $f$ is said to be uniforemly differentiable, whenever there exists $\varepsilon >0$, such that ${{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}\over{\Delta z}}$ tends to $f^{'}(z)$, as $\Delta z \rightarrow 0$, uniformly on $z\in B(K,\varepsilon)$.}}

{{Note that in Walter Rudin(principles of mathematical analysis) exersis 8, Chapter 5(differentiability),  uniformely differentiable real function is defined. 
}}

Comment: What is the definition of "uniformly differentiable"?

Comment: What is the definition of an analytic function on a *compact* set? One usually requires the Cauchy-Riemann equations to hold in a neighborhood of every point...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal The standard meaning is that for every point of the domain there is an analytic function defined on an open set containing the point and coinciding with the given function on the intersection of the domains. Since $K$ is compact, this is the same as saying that there is an open set containing $K$ and an analytic function defined on this set, whose restriction to $K$ coincides with the given function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Let's state the assumptions more precisely: $f$ is holomorphic  in a domain $\Omega$, and $K\subset \Omega$ is a compact set. Let $\tilde K$ be a closed $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $K$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough so that $\tilde K\subset \Omega$. Let $M$ be the maximum of $f''$ on $\tilde K$.

If $|\Delta z|<\epsilon$, then using the formula 
$$
\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z} = \int_0^1 f'(z+t\Delta z)\,dt
$$
together with the fact that $|f'(z)+t\Delta z)-f'(z)|\le M | \Delta z|$, we conclude with 
$$
\left|\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z} -f'(z)\right| \le M | \Delta z|
$$
The estimate is uniform in $z$.